# Pull row based on Column Match from multiple tables

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to do the following and am stuck.

I have an excel spreadsheet with 3 tabs.

1. One tab is an input file
2. Second tab is a set of data
3. Third tab is a set of data

For #1, the first tab contains has a list of file names and where they are located.[image]
I then use power query to combine those two columns, FileNames and QuickCheck here to produce my table that I want to run "Quick Checks" against.:

[image]

For #2 and #3, those tabs contain customer data

[image]

[image]

Basically, with power query, how do I run a search where If the Custom column in 1 matches the quick check column in #1,  pull that row of data and output it to another tab?  My desired output file needs to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you want to create a new table, where you want tabs #2 & #3 to be merged, and no rows with empty "check"? What is the role of tab #1?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the query #1 and #2 using the Merge Queries button and then expanding the new column it generates by clicking on the button with the two arrows in the column header. You can do the same merge with queries #1 and #3, and then append those two queries together using the Append Queries button.

If you want to keep queries 1-3 unmodified, you can Duplicate or Reference the query you're going to use as the left table by expanding the queries pane (next to the table preview in the editor), right-clicking on the query name in the queries pane and selecting the relevant context menu item. You can then do the merge step on that without modifying the original query.